# Regex remove numerics between two strings

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to retrieve a string, ignoring all numerics between two other strings using regex

In my example below, ABC, DEF and HIJ will always be the same value, and in the same position of the string being searched, but 123 and 456 will always be different values and lengths.

My example string is:

```
"ABC 123 456 DEF HIJ"
```

I am trying to be left with the result of:

```
"DEF"
```

I can do this with two lines by using

```
r'ABC (.*) HIJ'
```

Which leaves me with 123 456 DEF where I could then:

```
r'[^0-9\s]'
```

It seems like that should be possible, but I really can't seem to figure it out if it is.

Comment: Will the term you are looking for always be the 2nd last word on the line?  Just out of curiosity I hope it's not always DEF :)

Comment: HIJ will always be the last and ABC always the first

Comment: I was  wondering if you could use the fact that you are looking for the 2nd last word at the end of the sentence to come up with something short.

Comment: You should show a **real** example.

Comment: Isn't "real example" a bit of an oxymoron? I thought it was fairly well explained, yet I still got the down vote. Thanks

Comment: Would I be abusing oxymoron if I upvoted you both?

Comment: No it isn't since you actually have three different answers since one hour (each one has a different interpretation of your question) and you don't have accepted any of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regex `\d+` will match 1 or more digits (greedy).

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "ABC 123 456 DEF HIJ"
>>> pat = r'ABC \d+ \d+ (.*) HIJ'
>>> re.findall(pat, s)
['DEF']
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending on exactly what is fixed in your input data, you could try extracting the second "word", allowing for (and ignoring) intervening strings of digits with a pattern like this:

```
foo = "ABC 123 456 DEF 456 HIJ"
pat = r'\w+\s+[\d ]*(\w+)[\d ]*\w+'
re.findall(pat, foo)
['DEF']
```

Alternatively, regexps might not be the easiest way.  You could use a single regexp to strip out all numeric characters, split the remaining string on whitespace, and take the second element.

Comment: Apparently the staff found out you send this answer from Antarctica. Good job on a good answer and being [presumably the first](https://twitter.com/i/web/status/827536984176476163) to send a post from the 7th continent!

Answer (score 0):

How about the regular expression:  (Updated due to the first comment)

([A-Za-z]+)\ [A-Za-z]+$

It will capture the first of 2 words split by a space at the end of the line.

```
import re

s = "ABC 123123123 1231231234 DEF HIJ"
pat = r'([A-Za-z]+)\ [A-Za-z]+$'
a = re.findall(pat,s)
print (a)
```

gives 'DEF'

To capture multiple words in that position you could modify the pattern to:

```
r'\ ([A-Za-z\ ]+)\ [A-Za-z]+$'
```

For an input of ABC 234234  46456456 DEF ZYX HIJ, this will give you 'DEF ZYX'.

If you want to enforce that the first string must be ABC and the last one HIJ, then the other answer by [wim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim) will do the trick.

Comment: Take a look at the ascii table and you will understand that `[A-z]` isn't what you think and doesn't contain only letters.

Comment: Damn punctuation, should have sticked with [A-Za-z].  Updated to reflect your input.  Must admit I haven't looked at the ASCII table since I was building 'UI's' with ALT codes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on "ABC, DEF and HIJ will always be the same value, and in the same position of the string being searched, but 123 and 456 will always be different values and lengths":

```
>>> re.sub("ABC \d+ \d+ DEF HIJ", "DEF", "foo1 ABC 12345 67890 DEF HIJ foo2")
'foo1 DEF foo2'
```